# Add a Skip Ad button to Brightcove Player

Tags: brightcove

I'm trying to add a Skip Ad Button to my Brightcove Player but I don't know hot to do it.   Brightcoves supports tell me that I need to create a plugin with a custom component to my player, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you read the [ask] page and the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how to use and build SWF plugins:
http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/creating-custom-player-components

And then use the stopAD method in the AdvertisingModue
https://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/player/com/brightcove/api/modules/AdvertisingModule.html#stopAd()